# adding a column to an output file with multiple entries

Tags: text-processing

I have 2 files with the following data:

file 1

```
22:50:48] Return_M
22:50:49] Return_A
22:50:50] Return_F
22:50:51] Return_K
22:50:52] Return_Y
```

file 2

```
22:50:48] <0> X led_required
22:50:48] <0> X start_rules
22:50:48] <0> X leadstart
22:50:49] <0> X asynchronous_start
22:50:49] <0> X controldown
22:50:49] <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:49] <0> X limiting_rules
22:50:50] <0> X stock_manager
22:50:50] <0> X led_blink
22:50:50] <0> X start_required 
22:50:51] <0> X control_down
22:50:51] <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:51] <0> X start_rules
22:50:52] <0> X stock_manager
22:50:52] <0> X blink_led
```

I want to have a single file that outputs the following:

```
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X led_required
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X start_rules
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X leadstart
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X asynchronous_start
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X controldown
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X limiting_rules
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X stock_manager
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X led_blink
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X start_required 
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X control_down
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X start_rules
22:50:52] Return_Y <0> X stock_manager
22:50:52] Return_Y <0> X blink_led
```

It basically puts the return codes from file 1 into file 2 to but only at the matching time.

Answer (score 1):

I've included two (slightly different) scripts that should do what you want: a Python script and a Bash script.

### Python Solution

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""prefix_join.py"""

import sys

input_1 = sys.argv[1]
input_2 = sys.argv[2]

# Initialize a list to store prefixes as they occur
prefix_list = list()

# Parse the first input file
data_1 = dict()
with open(input_1, "r") as file_1:
    for line in file_1:

        # Remove trailing and leading whitespace
        line = line.strip()

        # Split the string on the first whitespace character
        prefix, sep, suffix = line.partition(" ")

        # Add the prefix the list of prefixes
        if prefix not in prefix_list:
            prefix_list.append(prefix)

        # Add the prefix to the first data dictionary
        if prefix not in data_1:
            data_1[prefix] = list()

        # Add the suffix to the data dictionary
        data_1[prefix].append(suffix)

# Parse the second input file
data_2 = dict()
with open(input_2, "r") as file_2:
    for line in file_2:

        # Remove trailing and leading whitespace
        line = line.strip()

        # Split the string on the first whitespace character
        prefix, sep, suffix = line.partition(" ")

        # Add the prefix the list of prefixes
        if prefix not in prefix_list:
            prefix_list.append(prefix)

        # Add the prefix to the first data dictionary
        if prefix not in data_2:
            data_2[prefix] = list()

        # Add the suffix to the data dictionary
        data_2[prefix].append(suffix)

# Output the joined data
for prefix in prefix_list:
    for value_1 in data_1.get(prefix, list()):
        for value_2 in data_2.get(prefix, list()):
            output_line = "{} {} X {}".format(prefix, value_1, value_2)
            print(output_line)
```

You would run it like this:

```bsh
python prefix_join.py file-1.txt file-2.txt
```

On your example data, it produces the following output:

```
22:50:48] Return_M X <0> X led_required
22:50:48] Return_M X <0> X start_rules
22:50:48] Return_M X <0> X leadstart
22:50:49] Return_A X <0> X asynchronous_start
22:50:49] Return_A X <0> X controldown
22:50:49] Return_A X <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:49] Return_A X <0> X limiting_rules
22:50:50] Return_F X <0> X stock_manager
22:50:50] Return_F X <0> X led_blink
22:50:50] Return_F X <0> X start_required
22:50:51] Return_K X <0> X control_down
22:50:51] Return_K X <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:51] Return_K X <0> X start_rules
22:50:52] Return_Y X <0> X stock_manager
22:50:52] Return_Y X <0> X blink_led
```

### Bash Solution

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# prefix-join.sh

# Get the input files as command-line arguments
input_file_1="$1"
input_file_2="$2"

# Set the internal field separator to be a newline (don't include spaces or tabs)
IFS=$'\n'

# Iterate over the lines of the first input file
for line_1 in $(cat "${input_file_1}"); do

    # Split the line on the first space
    prefix_1="${line_1/ */}";
    suffix_1="${line_1#*] }";

    # Iterate over the lines of the second input file
    for line_2 in $(cat "${input_file_2}"); do

        # Split the line on the first space
        prefix_2="${line_2/ */}";
        suffix_2="${line_2#*] }";

        # If the prefixes agree, combine the suffixes and output the result
        if [[ "${prefix_1}" = "${prefix_2}" ]]; then
            echo "${prefix_1} ${suffix_1} X ${suffix_2}"
        fi 

    done
done
```

You would run it like this:

```bsh
bash prefix-join.sh file-1.txt file-2.txt
```

On your sample data, this produces the same output as the Python script.

Comment: Thank you for that, but is there anyway we can do that in shell?

Comment: @VineethThomas What version of Bash (assuming you're using Bash) are you using?

Comment: @VineethThomas I added a (slightly different, less robust) Bash solution.

Answer (score 0):

I Done by below command

command

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do j=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $1}' g1.txt`;k=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $NF}' g1.txt`;awk -v j="$j" -v k="$k" '$1==j{print $1,k,$2,$3,$4}' g2.txt;done
```

output

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do j=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $1}' g1.txt`;k=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{print $NF}' g1.txt`;awk -v j="$j" -v k="$k" '$1==j{print $1,k,$2,$3,$4}' g2.txt;done

22:50:48] Return_M <0> X led_required
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X start_rules
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X leadstart
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X asynchronous_start
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X controldown
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X limiting_rules
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X stock_manager
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X led_blink
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X start_required
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X control_down
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X start_rules
22:50:52] Return_Y <0> X stock_manager
22:50:52] Return_Y <0> X blink_led
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is a re-run of [my previous answer to you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507721/116858) (on a newer question, but I missed this question when it was fresh)

Assuming the two files are sorted, which they appear to be:

```
$ join file1 file2
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X led_required
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X start_rules
22:50:48] Return_M <0> X leadstart
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X asynchronous_start
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X controldown
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:49] Return_A <0> X limiting_rules
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X stock_manager
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X led_blink
22:50:50] Return_F <0> X start_required
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X control_down
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X select_set(3)
22:50:51] Return_K <0> X start_rules
22:50:52] Return_Y <0> X stock_manager
22:50:52] Return_Y <0> X blink_led
```

The `join` utility performs a [relational INNER JOIN operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) on its two input files.  By default, the first column is the join column, and the input *needs* to be sorted on this column.

The other thing, which is different for this question compared to the newer one, is to note the ordering of the columns.  By default, `join` always puts the join column first, followed by all columns from the first file and then all columns from the second file.

You may change this order by using the `-o` flag with `join` (see manual).