# creating new columns

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

i have two input files like this
file 1

```
 a  1 
 b  2 
 c  3 
 d  4
```

file 2

```
 a
 a
 b
 c
 c
 c
 d 
 d
```

how can i create a shell script to  have the following output

```
 a  1 
 a  1 
 b  2 
 c  3 
 c  3 
 c  3 
 d  4 
 d  4
```

I have tried the paste method and that will only paste the corresponding numbers in order not matching the alphabet. any kinda guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Related from the same user: [adding a column to an output file with multiple entries](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/507526)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that both files are sorted on the first column:

```
$ join file1 file2
a 1
a 1
b 2
c 3
c 3
c 3
d 4
d 4
```

The `join` utility performs a [relational INNER JOIN operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) on its two input files.  By default, the first column is the join column, and the input *needs* to be sorted on this column.

Answer (score 1):

With awk, reading the first file into an array and printing from that based on the second file. The inputs don't need to be sorted here:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1] = $2; next } { print $1, a[$1] }' file1 file2
a 1
a 1
b 2
c 3
c 3
c 3
d 4
d 4
```

Comment: this doesn't display anything nor can i output to a file.

Comment: @VineethThomas, it works for the sample inputs you showed, if they're stored in files named `file1` and `file2` in the current directory. You can store the output in a file with the usual output redirection `> outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need shell script for this, but if you want (e.g. if you don't have join, grep, etc), this one is only-builtin needed:

```
#you should not have spaces in start of file1.txt or file2.txt
search_first_col(){ 
         while read -r col nextcol ; do 
            case $col in "$1") 
                    echo "$col $nextcol" ;; 
            esac 
         done 
       }
while IFS= read -r lin ; do 
       search_first_col "$lin" </tmp/file1.txt
done </tmp/file2.txt
```

Comment: Ignoring the issue that this launches `grep` for each line of `file2`, you probably want to lock the pattern to start of line `^` and to whitespace at the end  to avoid matching on substrings. But you'll still get issues with fields that look like regular expression patterns. Or use `grep -wF`, but that might still match the second column of `file1`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, ah right, `-w` might work but it's still bad. (and not standard.)

Comment: `join` and `grep` are POSIX (though `join` isn't that commonly used, so there might be embedded systems without it. E.g. my Busybox doesn't have it...)

Comment: If you're going to do that `while read` thing, you might want to use `while read -r key value; do if [ "$key" = "$1" ] ... ; done < file1` to handle the columns separately?

Comment: @ilkkachu adjusted as suggested. Can you test in your busybox? If not I think we can select the columns using for...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried by below method and its worked fine

```
for i in `cat file1| awk '{print $1}'`; do h=`awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i{print $2}' file1`;awk -v i="$i" -v h="$h" '$1==i{print $0 " " h}' file2;done
```

output

```
for i in `cat file1| awk '{print $1}'`; do h=`awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i{print $2}' file1`;awk -v i="$i" -v h="$h" '$1==i{print $0 " " h}' file2;done
a 1
 a 1
 b 2
 c 3
 c 3
 c 3
 d  4
 d 4
```

Answer (score 0):

with Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases)

```
mlr --nidx --fs " " join -j 1 -f file2 file2
```

you have

```
a 1
a 1
b 2
c 3
c 3
c 3
d 4
d 4
```